# Regex to see if ip starts with 156.21.x.x

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm writing a regex for google analytics and I need to block any IP from 156.21.x.x I don't care about the last 2 octets just the first two. I would like to keep the regex to as few characters as possible as google only allows 255 chars and my regex is already pretty large.

Comment: You employ primary the words `I want` in your question. I cannot see the words `I have tried the following ... but it didn't work`. You know the kind of things that indicate that you put some effort into solving this issue and not just enjoying your beer stein while others are writing the code for you.

Comment: I've tried almost everything I've found online....I have this which works, but brings me over the 255 char limit when attached to my other regexs

^156\.21\.\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b\.\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what flavor of regex or what lang your using, but this will work on most regex engines:

```
156\.21\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

Of course, this will match invalid ip's like 156.21.777.888, but if the list your parsing doesnt contain invalid ip addresses, then you should be ok.  Or:

```
156\.21(\.\d{1,3}){2}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running short on space, this would work, though you would match non-IP addresses as well.  If you can assume Google will give you valid IP addresses, this is your shortest option:

```
^156\.21\.
```

Matches things like: `156.21.1.1` `156.21.1000.1000` `156.21.ABC`

But does not match `http://156.21.1.1` `ehlo 156.21.1000.1000`

Answer (score 1):

The following regex would match (almost) valid IPv4 addresses that starts with 156.21:

```
(156\.21(?:\.[\d]{1,3}){2})
```